# Help with: $p$ and $q$ are primes, then a group of order $p^2q$ cannot be simple

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

If $p$ and $q$ are primes, than a group of order $p^2q$ cannot be simple.

The proof is given as follow:

Assume that G is simple and $ p \neq q$. The number of $p$-Sylow subgroups must be $q$ and hence $q \equiv 1 \mod p$. Hence, $q > p$. The number of $q$-Sylow subgroups is either $p$ or $p^
2$. It cannot be $p$, because this would imply that $p \equiv 1 \mod q$ implying $p > q$.

Hence, the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups must be $p^2$. But any pair of these subgroups can have only the identity as a common element.
Here I got confused. Why is it true? Suppose we have that $p^2$ $q$-Sylow subgroups $Q_1,\dots, Q_{p^2}$. Why we have that $$Q_j \neq Q_i \;\Rightarrow Q_i \cap Q_j = \{e\}$$

Furthermore why we get than that $\vert Q_1 \cup \dots \cup Q_{p^2} \vert=1 +p^2*(q-1)$?

EDIT: In my textbook it uses also the following statement: Let $P_1, \dots, P_q$ be the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Then $\vert P_1 \cup \dots \cup P_q \vert \geq \vert P_1 \cup P_2 \vert \geq  p^2+(p^2-p)$. How we get there the last inequality $\vert P_1 \cup P_2 \vert \geq  p^2+(p^2-p)$?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ and $K$ are different subgroups of $G$ of order $q$ a prime, then $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and by Lagrange $|H \cap K|$ divides $|H|=q$. Since $q$ is prime, $H \cap K=H$, impossible since $H$ and $K$ are different, or $H \cap K=1$.

To finish the argument: hence there are $p^2(q-1)$ elements of order $q$. That leaves $|G|-p^2(q-1)=p^2$ elements of $p$-power order, so these consitute the Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p^2$ which must be normal, whence $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Thanks for your first part, the book uses a quiet different way to end the proof - please see my edit

Comment: The intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is trivial or a group of order $p$, assuming that these subgroups are *different*. Can you finish?

Comment: Why it can be a group of order $p$?

Comment: Well $P_1 \cap P_2$ is a subgroup of $P_1$ (and $P_2$). But $|P_1|=|P_2|=p^2$. Hence, by Lagrange,  $|P_1 \cap P_2| \in \{1,p,p^2\}$. But it cannot be $|P_1 \cap P_2|=p^2$, since then $P_1 \cap P_2=P_1$, so $P_1 \subseteq P_2$ and because $|P_1|=|P_2|$ we would have $P_1=P_2$. So $|P_1 \cap P_2| = 1$ or $p$. In the first case, $|P_1 \cup P_2|=2p^2-1$, in the latter case $|P_1 \cup P_2|=2(p^2-p)+p$. In any case $|P_1 \cup P_2| \geq 2p^2-p$. Hope this explains it. Draw a Venn diagram!

Comment: @FrederickManfred If you deem my answer to your post the right one, please tick it as such, as is the habit here on Math StackExchange. Thanks!